# Rails: NoMethodError - undefined method `record_type`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, json-api

I am working on a Rails 6 API only application using
[jsonapi-serializer](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer) gem.

I am using namespaces for the resources in my application, I also used namespaces for the serializer files.

So my serializer file looks like this:

```
module Applyportal
  class ApplicantSerializer
    include JSONAPI::Serializer
    attributes :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :username, :password,  :nationality, :state_of_origin, :local_government

    belongs_to :local_government, serializer: Personalinfo::LocalGovernment
    belongs_to :marital_status, serializer: Personalinfo::MaritalStatus
    belongs_to :nationality, serializer: Personalinfo::Nationality
    has_many :applications, serializer: Applyportal::Application
    cache_options store: Rails.cache, namespace: 'jsonapi-serializer', expires_in: 1.hour
  end
end
```

But when I try to make a Post request to this resource I get the error below:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `record_type' for #<Class:0x00007f05d4d451f8>
Did you mean?  record_timestamps)
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was coming from how I defined my serializer associations

**Here's how I solved it**:

So I used namespaces for the resources in my application, I also used namespaces for the serializer files.

So my serializer file looked like this:

```
module Applyportal
  class ApplicantSerializer
    include JSONAPI::Serializer
    attributes :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :username, :password,  :nationality, :state_of_origin, :local_government

    belongs_to :local_government, serializer: Personalinfo::LocalGovernment
    belongs_to :marital_status, serializer: Personalinfo::MaritalStatus
    belongs_to :nationality, serializer: Personalinfo::Nationality
    has_many :applications, serializer: Applyportal::Application
    cache_options store: Rails.cache, namespace: 'jsonapi-serializer', expires_in: 1.hour
  end
end
```

I was missing to add `Serializer` at the end of each association which was making it difficult for the rails application to find the `record_type`, so instead of:

```
belongs_to :local_government, serializer: Personalinfo::LocalGovernment
```

it should be

```
belongs_to :local_government, serializer: Personalinfo::LocalGovernmentSerializer
```

So my serializer file looked like this afterwards:

```
module Applyportal
  class ApplicantSerializer
    include JSONAPI::Serializer
    attributes :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :username, :password,  :nationality, :state_of_origin, :local_government

    belongs_to :local_government, serializer: Personalinfo::LocalGovernmentSerializer
    belongs_to :marital_status, serializer: Personalinfo::MaritalStatusSerializer
    belongs_to :nationality, serializer: Personalinfo::NationalitySerializer
    has_many :applications, serializer: Applyportal::ApplicationSerializer
    cache_options store: Rails.cache, namespace: 'jsonapi-serializer', expires_in: 1.hour
  end
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**